# For each loop: can we populate an array?

Tags: java

I can read data from an array with for each syntax:

```
int[] a = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    a[i] = i;
}


for (int element : a){
    System.out.println(element);                         
}
```

But is it possible to populate the array likewise. Say, with `i*2` values?
I failed to invent such a method and would rather ask you whether I'm wrong or not.

Comment: You can't access indexes using *for each* loop. Use the first instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html),

> The for-each loop hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove.
>   Therefore, the for-eachloop is not usable for filtering. Similarly
>   it is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a
>   list or array as you traverse it. Finally, it is not usable for loops
>   that must iterate over multiple collections in parallel. These
>   shortcomings were known by the designers, who made a conscious
>   decision to go with a clean, simple construct that wouldcover the
>   great majority of cases.

So, in simple words, its not possible to populate arrays.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. An enhanced for loop can only iterate over a collection - in your case, you don't *have* useful values in a collection to start with - only a collection you're trying to populate.

If you're just trying to populate one array based on some calculation which *isn't* based on an existing collection, an enhanced for loop isn't helpful.

Even if you *do* want to populate the array based on another collection, using an enhanced for loop isn't ideal, as you don't have any concept of an index. For example, if you have a `String` array and you want to populate an `int` array with the lengths of the strings, you *can* do:

```
String[] words = ...; // Populate the array
int[] lengths = new int[words.length];

int index = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    lengths[index++] = word.length();
}
```

... but it's not ideal. It's better if you're populating a `List` of course, as then you can just call `add`:

```
String[] words = ...; // Populate the array
List<Integer> lengths = new ArrayList<Integer>(words.length);

for (String word : words) {
    lengths.add(word.length());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. You'll have to use your first version of the for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no counter for the current index, just the value at the index inthe foreach loop hence it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to assign values to the actual array you are using in an enhanced for each loop. This is because an enhanced for-each loop does not give you access to the array's pointers. In order to change the values of the array, you must literally say:

```
a[i] = anything
```

You can however, use an enhanced for-loop to assign values to another array like so:

```
int[] nums = new int[4];
int[] setNums = {0,1,2,3};
i = 0;
for(int e: setNums) {
   nums[i++] = e*2;
}
```

Enhanced for-loops in Java merely offer a little syntactic sugar to get the values of the an array or List. In some ways, they operate similarly to passing Objects to a method - the original Object passed to the method cannot be re-assigned in the method. For example:

```
int i = 1;
void multiplyAndPrint(int p) {
  p = p*2;
  System.out.println(p);
}
System.out.println(i);
```

Will print 2 and then 1. This is the same issue you will run into attempting to assign values from a for-each loop.

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you would need a way to get the index of 'element' in your array.

[How to find the index of an element in an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522108/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-in-java) has a lot of suggestions on how to do that.