# Java Array with minValue

Tags: java

I am Java Beginner. I made a class and a method which is to return the minimum number in the array. But I can't figure out why it is not working well.

Below is Code.

```
package array;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Value {
    public static int minValue(int[] arr) {
        for(int e : arr) {
            if(arr[0] > e) {
                arr[0] = e;
            }
        }
        return arr[0];
    }
}
public class ArrayTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    System.out.print("Input Number : ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int e : arr) {
        e = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("min : " + Value.minValue(arr));
}
```

The result is "min : 0 "
What's the problem with my code???

Comment: `e = sc.nextInt();` You never add `e` to the array.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169703/for-each-loop-can-we-populate-an-array. You have to use the normal for version and not the for-each version for populating your array

Comment: Thank you everybody. Now, I can know the reason. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change only the method of taking input nothing else,
I have added a right one you can use this.

```
  int i = 0;
  for (int e: arr) {
  arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
  i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me try and run it down. 
You create an array of integers with length of 5 index, ask the user for 5 numbers, add these numbers to the array arr as the user enters them. I see that in the for loop

```
for(int e : arr) {
    e = sc.nextInt();
}
```

e is being assigned the user input but it is not passing that into the array arr. Looks like you need to add a statement to pass/add the user input into the array.

Comment: I would use for loop like this; for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {arr[i] = sc.nextInt();}

Comment: To keep your code with the for each loop you would just replace e with arr[e]

Answer (score -2):

i think this may help you

```
    public static int minValue(int[] arr) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int e : arr) {
            if(e < min) {
                min = e;
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
```

and also change this

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
 }
```

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the `minValue` method.

Comment: if that method is used, it will change the original array at index 0