# Java arrays returning highest array index

Tags: java, max

I am supposed to write a program that finds the largest index in an unsorted array of integers.

> Use a method that takes an array of integers as a parameter. The method should search the array and return the index of the largest value.

So i wrote a program that returns the highest value, for example it returns 13 as the highest number instead of the index of 2. So how would i return the index instead of the highest number itself? If that is an easy fix, does the rest of my code look correct? Thanks!

```
public class LargestInteger 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] largeArray = {5,4,13,7,7,8,9,10,5};

        System.out.println(findLargest(largeArray));
    }

    public static int findLargest(int array[])
    {
        int largest = array[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] > largest)
                largest = array[i];   
        }

        return largest;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to return `index` only, simply change `largest = array[i]; ` to `largest = i;`

Comment: Relevent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522108/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-in-java

Comment: Be careful with your wording.  What you asked is NOT what the problem statement you pasted says.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder an example of [XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @RhinoFeeder How is it not?

Comment: You are telling us you want the highest array index (array.length-1).  But what you actually want is the index containing the highest value.  They are two different hings.

Answer (score 3):

Can also done with,

```
int[] largeArray     = {5,4,13,7,7,8,9,10,5};
int   largestElement = findLargest(largeArray);
int   index          = Arrays.asList(5,4,13,7,7,8,9,10,5).indexOf(largestElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

In java 8 you can do it simply:

To get the highest:

```
int[] largeArray = {5,4,13,7,7,8,9,10,5};
System.out.println(IntStream.of(largeArray).max().getAsInt());
```

> result: 13

And to sum them:

```
System.out.println(IntStream.of(largeArray).sum());
```

> result: 68

Comment: The OPs question was to find the index, not the max value (although the code posted by the OP is incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep and store the largest index. Try this:

```
public static int findLargest(int array[])
{
    int largest = array[0];
    int largestIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > largest) {
            largest = array[i]; 
            largestIndex =i;
        }  
    }

    return largestIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `for` loop at the end of the method, and a variable like `index`. Search through the list and find if the variable matches, remembering to increment the `index` variable every time.

Example:

```
int index = 0;
for (int i : array)
{
    if (i == largest)
    {
         break;
    }
    index++;
}
return index;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add aditional method that gets largest number and an array then search for index of that number:

```
public class LargestInteger 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] largeArray = {5,4,13,7,7,8,9,10,5};

        System.out.println(indexOfLargest(largeArray, findLargest(largeArray)));
    }

    public static int findLargest(int array[])
    {
        int largest = array[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] > largest)
                largest = array[i];   
        }

        return largest;
    }

    public static int indexOfLargest(int array[], int number)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == number)
                return i;            
        }

        return -1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought we need a simple answer in the era of stream interface. If your array is `int[] a`, you can get **argmax** (the index of the largest value) with the following code:

```
IntStream.range(0, a.length).boxed().max(Comparator.comparing(i->a[i])).get();
```

If you want **argmin**, just change `max()` to `min()`. Because it compares elements in their natural order, any array with comparable elements will do, like `double[]` or `long[]`.