# how to find the index of an item in an array java

Tags: java, arrays, hash

I want to find the index of the start up letter and then show the index of that item in array or array list in java.
Example: I have:

```
String[] arr={"apple","at","book","bad","car","cat"};
```

when I input a: then i will get index =0, b: i will get index=2, c: i will get index=4

Because my array item is over 20,000 , so using linear Search is too slow.
and my list is unsorted, so i can't use Binary Search also.
I want to get index of the item like the example above, what can i solve with this?

Comment: Is the array dynamic or is it constant?

Comment: If you have an unsorted list, the index of one arbitrary item starting with letter x is pretty useless, I think.

Comment: the array is constant

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-in-java]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522108/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-in-java

Comment: because i can't sort my array to the sorted list, because it is not in English, it is in Vietnamese. I can't sort word in Vietnamese

Comment: @Ganesh That is not a duplicate.

Comment: If the array is constant, maybe you can find the indexes for each letter in advance and then use the stored indexes when needed.

Comment: How can i find the index of each letter?

Comment: If i use this linear Search, it seem to work slow with the size of big array.

Comment: Compile a map of index to first character when building the array.

Comment: can u show me code? i seem not yet understand

Comment: Are you able to interrupt the construction of this array? If yes, store the starting character and the actual array index in a map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the indexes of words starting with a certain letter then try this one:

While adding the Words to your Array/list (that will hold all your words) you could also add it to a map that will hold all indexes for every first letters.

```
 Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

 public void yourmethod() {
    //adding all your words to an Array/arraylist goes here. (arr[] in this case)

    string firstLetter = yourword.substring(0,1);

    if(myMap.constainsKey(firstLetter)) {
       myMap.get(letter).add(yourword);
    } else {
         myMap.put(firstLetter, yourword);
    }
 }
```

Comment: So, if the user continue type the next letter, example: ap ? so can it help, sir?

Comment: ap? didnt you say the startup letter (one letter)?

Comment: not only one, the search is like the search word in Dictionary. one letter , the one more letter, ...

Comment: So you will be able to search for i.e.: a, ap, app, appl, apple to in this case get index 0 and if you only type the a letter you will get index 0 and 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run some initialization code (before the user starts to type letters in).

```
// initialize an array that has a cell for each letter with value -1
int[] firstIndexes = new int[26];
for(int i=0;i<firstIndexes.length;i++) {
    firstIndexes[i] = -1;
}

// loop over original array and look for each letter's first occurence
for(int i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++) {
    char c=wordsArray[i][0];
    if(firstIndexes[c-'a'] < 0) {
        firstIndexes[c-'a'] = i;
    }
}
```

Then when the user types a letter you just need to find its index in the 'firstIndexes' array.