# Index of an element in an array using Java

Tags: java, arrays

The following code in Java return -1. I thought that it should return 3.

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6}; 
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(4));
```

Can you help me understand how this function works.

Thanks

Comment: `Arrays.asList` does not work for primitive arrays. It gives a `List<int[]>` containing the original `int[]`. -1 means that 4 is not one of the `List` items

Comment: `Arrays.asList(int[])` is creating a `List` of one element which contains the whole `int[]` array.  Change `int[]` to `Integer[]` instead

Comment: Trying writing the generic type of `asList` explicitly (`Arrays.<int>asList(array)`) rather than relying on type inference, and the compiler will tell you why that doesn't work.

Comment: [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Ints.asList()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)) addresses this problem; [more info](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained).

Answer (score 13):

Before Java 5, `Arrays.asList` used to accept an `Object[]`. When generics and varargs were introduced into the language this was changed to

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... arr)
```

In your example, `T` cannot be `int` because `int` is a primitive type. Unfortunately, the signature matches with `T` equal to `int[]` instead, which is a reference type. The result is that you end up with a `List` containing an array, not a `List` of integers.

In Java 4, your code would not have compiled because an `int[]` is not an `Object[]`. Not compiling is preferable to producing a strange result, and in Effective Java, Josh Bloch says retrofitting `asList` to be a varargs method was a mistake.

Answer (score 9):

`Arrays.asList` expect an object (or more). Your array (`array`)  is a sole object, thus calling the method will create a list of only one object, which is your array.

Calling `indexOf` on your list will return -1 because `4` will never be found as your list contains the array object, not the list of datas that your array contains.

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).indexOf(4);
```

should do what you want while keeping the original `int[]`.

You get an `IntStream` of it, box it into a `Stream<Integer>`, collect it to a `List<Integer>` and then can do an `.indexOf()` search.

Comment: You might want to use an `IntStream` instead of storing the all array into a list for calling `indexOf` - `OptionalInt index = IntStream.range(0, array.length).filter(i -> array[i] == 4).findFirst();`

Answer (score 4):

You've got answers as as to what is happening to your array when you use `Arrays.asList()`.

Other things to consider:

- Since your array is sorted, consider `Arrays.binarySearch()`
- If your array is not sorted, a simple custom indexOf method can perform the same without wasting cycles converting the `int[]` to a `List<Integer>`

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.print("Binary Search: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(array, 4));

    int[] array2 = {5, 8, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1};
    System.out.print("Manual Search: ");
    System.out.println(indexOf(array2, 4));
}

public static int indexOf(int[] array, int search) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == search) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Results:

```
Binary Search: 3
Manual Search: 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using an array of primitive type, this will not work. The array is of type int. Were you using `Integer` type for example, that will work.
-1 means the index of the specified element was not found.

This is what you want to do:

```
Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(4));
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use primitive types such as int as parameters to generic classes in Java since int is not a class,you shoud use Integer instead :

```
Integer[] array = {1,2,3,3,4,5}; 

List Arraylist=Arrays.asList(array);
System.out.println(Arraylist.indexOf(1));
System.out.println(Arraylist.indexOf(4));
```

output:

```
0
4
```

note that `Arraylist.indexOf(i)` return the index of first occurrence of the element **i** in list :

```
System.out.println(Arraylist.indexOf(3));
```

it will return `2` which is first occurrence of element 3 , not `3` since there is 2 elements of 3 in list.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you do this with a primary data type array, it will be treated as the first element in the List.

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
```

You will get this:

```
[[I@474e8d67]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

- In java `array` is considered as an `Object`
- `int[]` is particularly `Object` and not `Object[]`
- To call `Arrays.asList` you need zero or more `Objects`

Your method gets called in this way,

```
Arrays.asList((Object)(array));//Yes
Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);//No
```

So you will have `List<int[]>` and not `List<Integer>`

> Now, you might have asked your self that if `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)`
>   works than why not `Arrays.asList(arrayInt)` ?

In `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)` all the values are *autoboxed* in to the `Integer` which is solely an `Object` so in above case `Integer[]` cad do the trick.