# how do i make it so nextLine equals two strings in an array

Tags: java

I am trying to get my string letters to show me the index for every letter given as input. For example when I input `a` it returns 0 which is the index. Currently if I input a word with letter `a` and `b` it wont return anything. But it should return 0 and 1.

```
String[] code = {"a", "b","c", "d", "e"};

String letters=input.nextLine();

for (int i=0;i<code.length;i++) {
    if (letters.equals(code[i])) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: well .. what did you expect? "ab" is not a value withing "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", so your equals won't help you out there.

Comment: are you wanting to print the index the code variable where each letter in "letters" appears?

Comment: `nextLine()` - so only if it is contained on a separate line? so "ab" differs from "a" on first line then "b" on second line. It seems you will want to iterate this differently.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/1522108/125981 BUT your  question is somewhat unclear

Comment: I appreciate the comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to treat both elements the same way, as in:

```
for (char charFromUser : letters.toCharArray()) {
  for (int i=0; i < code.length; i++) {
    if (code[i] == charFromUser) {
      ... print i
```

In other words: you **intend** to compare characters, one by one. Then using `equals()` on the **complete** string given by the user doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through your input character by character in order to return more than one letter's index number

Comment: I'm asking if it can be done using nextLine or should i use something else

Answer (score 0):

Try somethink like this :

```
char[] List={'a','b','c','d'};

int count=0;
for(int i=0;i<List.length;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<input.length();j++) {
        if(input.charAt(j)==List[i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this agine

```
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] code = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.printf("please input:");
            String letters = input.nextLine();
            boolean isMatch = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {

                if (letters.equals(code[i])) {
                    isMatch = true;
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }

            if (!isMatch) {
                System.out.println("not equal");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@GhostCat answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543897/7694740), you are not comparing the characters in your input one by one with the values in your array. Another alternative is to use the built-in [`String::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) method to get this even easier:

```
String code = "abcde";
String letters = input.nextLine();

for (char c : letters.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.print(code.indexOf(c));
}
```

> - Input  >> ab
> - Output >> 01